# Find all the pairs in a network diagram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph-theory, shortest-path

I'm tying to solve a problem. I've a pandas DataFrame with columns Source, Target and Freq.

Let's assume I'm interested in Node 1. Node 1 can be linked in below way.

```
Source Target
5 1
3 5
2 3
6 2
```

5 is the source when 1 is the Target and 3 is the source when 5 is the target and the link goes on. I'm essentially trying to create a network graph which would b **6-2-3-5-1**.

Is there any way to programmatically find the all source-target combinations that would eventually end up in a **Target** of my choice?

**Edit**: Edited to provide more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to programmatically find the all source-target combinations

Yes, this is known as the [Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), that is given a graph *G* constructed of nodes/vertices *V* connected by edges *E* find the shortest path between source and target nodes. What you specify is a list of edges where each edge connects some node *v(i)* to another node *v(j)*.

There are several algorithms that implement a solution. You can use a library like [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) so you don't have to implement the algorithm yourself. For example,

```
# let's create the data frame as per your example
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        (5, 1),
        (3, 5),
        (2, 3),
        (6, 2),
    ], columns=['source', 'target'])

# import networkx and build the graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(df.values)

# import the shortest_paths generic algorithm
nx.shortest_path(G, source=6, target=1)
=> 
[6, 2, 3, 5, 1]
```

> find the all source-target combinations

NetworkX provides [many algorithms](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html) that you should match with the specific use-case you are trying to solve. To find all the possible paths given a source and a target node,

```
# assume we have added another edge source=6 target=1 
list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=6, target=1))
=> 
[[6, 1], [6, 2, 3, 5, 1]]
```

> all source-target combinations (...) that would eventually end up in a target of my choice

We want to find all possible source nodes and paths that eventually end up at a target of our choice, without specifying the source node:

```
# find all start/end nodes
import networkx as nx
# -- we need a directed graph
dG = nx.DiGraph()
dG.add_edges_from(df.values)
# -- find possible source nodes
source_nodes = [x for x in G.nodes_iter() if dG.out_degree(x) >= 1]
# -- for every source node find the shortest path to target
paths = [nx.shortest_path(G, source=source, target=1) for source in source_nodes]
paths
=>
[[2, 3, 5, 1], [3, 5, 1], [5, 1], [6, 2, 3, 5, 1]]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution. One update in Networkx 2.0 is that G.nodes_iter() has been removed. Their comment on their website. "One View example is G.nodes (or G.nodes()) which now returns a dict-like NodeView while G.nodes_iter() has been removed." 
Thanks.